# How can I random delete two value on python matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix

```
uvv=np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, ],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ],
              [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, ]])
```

According to above matrix, I would like to random to keep only two values of 1 in each row .

Target:

```
 uvv=np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ],
               [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ],
               [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, ]])
```

My current coding can keep only one 1 in each row. How can I fix this? or Do you have any idea?

```
uvv*=np.cumsum(uvv,axis=1)==1
```

Thanks

Comment: What does "keep only two values" mean ? You already have only two distinct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify your matrix such that only two occurrences of 1 are retained in each row, you can follow these steps:

1. For each row, find the indices where the value is 1.
2. Randomly shuffle these indices.
3. Keep only the first two indices (after shuffling) and set the rest to 0.

Here's how you can implement this in Python using NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

uvv = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, ],
               [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ],
               [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ],
               [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, ]])

for row in uvv:
    ones_idx = np.where(row == 1)[0]
    np.random.shuffle(ones_idx)
    keep_idx = ones_idx[:2]
    row[:] = 0
    row[keep_idx] = 1

print(uvv)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a vectorial method, you could multiply your array by a random array, and use [`argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) to identify the top 2 values.

Then, either modify the array in place by setting to `0` all values but the top `N`:

```
N = 2
r = uvv * np.random.random(size=uvv.shape)
uvv[np.arange(len(uvv))[:,None], np.argpartition(r, -N)[:, :-N]] = 0
```

Or create a new array with [`zeros_like`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros_like.html) and assign `1` to the top `N` values:

```
out = np.zeros_like(uvv)
N = 2
r = uvv * np.random.random(size=uvv.shape)
out[np.arange(len(uvv))[:,None], np.argpartition(r, -N)[:, -N:]] = 1
```

Example output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution to your question.

```
import numpy as np
uvv=np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, ],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ],
              [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, ]])
for i in range(0, len(uvv)):
    arr = np.arange(sum(uvv[i]))
    np.random.shuffle(arr)
    pos = 0
    for j in range(0, len(uvv[0])):
        if uvv[i][j]:
            if arr[pos] > 1:
                uvv[i][j] = 0
            pos += 1
print(uvv)
```

The output was

```
[[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0]]
```